# how to calculate moments and position per object instead of average across objects?

Tags: opencv

I'm using the following code to calculate the moments and the position of an object using opencv:

```
// calc object moments
CvMoments *moments = (CvMoments*) malloc(sizeof(CvMoments));
cvMoments(threshy, moments, 1);

// get the moment values
double moment10 = cvGetSpatialMoment(moments, 1, 0);
double moment01 = cvGetSpatialMoment(moments, 0, 1);
double area = cvGetCentralMoment(moments, 0, 0);

// save the X and Y position from previous iteration.
int lastX = currentX;
int lastY = currentY;

// calculate the new X and Y positions.
currentX = moment10/area;
currentY = moment01/area;
```

this works great, as long as there's only one object in the scene. If however there are multiple objects, `currentX` and `currentY` will result in the mid-point of all objects.

Is there a way to calculate the moments (and coordinates) of each object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to use countours for that. For C++ api you have a function called cv::findContours where you pass your thresholded image, after that you calculate the moments over each countour/object. Look up for more details in [OpenCV documentation](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#cv-findcontours).